# Random Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException

Tags: random, connection, ssas, cube, adomd.net

I got a problem with an AdomdConnection to SSAS. It works fine 99% of the time but sometimes I get the following error:

```
2012-07-25 09:58:47.5286|ERROR|BI.AdoMD.CubeConnectionAttribute|Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.GetTcpClient(ConnectionInfo   connectionInfo)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.GetTcpClient(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.OpenTcpConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect(Boolean toIXMLA)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
at BI.AdoMD.CubeConnectionAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in .
```

I can't seem to figure out what's causing this problem.

I've checked the server which is running the SSAS and it looks like it's no Authentication / firewall problem.

Hopefully someone encountered this problem before and knows what is causing these random connection problem.

-Rick

Answer (score 1):

You are geting a timeout trying to connect to the TCP port on the target machine.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond at
>   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)

It could be a transient loading issue for the server, or there could be some network issue that occaisionally occurs. Either way, it is not necessarily directly related to SSAS as such.

Answer (score 1):

As per Nat's answer above, I've seen this occasionally when the cube is under load - It seems to 'queue' incoming requests. Is it possible the cube is getting hit by a lot of queries at once, or a few heavy queries? Does this happen on/around cube processing times?

When I diagnosed something similar, I found setting up counters for connections and queries in Perfmon, and setting it to write them to disk for later cross-checking to be invaluable.